# Schema validation is not working?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am using java and cxf SOAP webservices. I have enabled schema validation as below but it is not working. I dont have any external xsds. All xsd elements are part of WSDL. Will `schemavlaidation= true` property does not work if it has no external xsd and all xsd elements are part of WSDL? I placed `minOccur` and `maxOccur` attributes.

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="serviceEndpoint" implementor="#serviceEndpoint"
        address="/CreateService" wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl/Service.wsdl">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Put you wsdl under WEB-INF folder and change `wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/Service.wsdl"`